# Identifying line where thread is in debugger

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to debug a multithreaded application where several threads seem to stall, and then continue working minutes later or never again.

I'm sure there is  a point of contention between them that is causing this, but I don't know how to find it. Using the `Parallel Stacks` and `Threads` view in Visual Studio only provides me with the stack from of where the threads were started, not where they currently are.

**I start my tasks with:**

```
Task task = new Task((object state) => { DoWork(state).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }, $"worker_task{i}", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

They then run through a process of pulling items from a `ConcurrentQueue` and processing them. I used the `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` else the async method they call immediately returns and the tasks show as complete even though there is still work being done.

**Visual Studio Debug windows:**

[image]

Thread #38880 is not actually doing any work, and I want to find out where it is getting stuck, but it only shows me where the task was started.

How can I see what line the task/thread is currently on? Am I starting my tasks in such a way that I cannot see this? If so, what should I be doing?

---

**Context:** I am running tasks that call API's via `Httpclient`. Because of the network latency I am running multiple tasks in parallel to maximize my cpu utilization during wait time. Calling Httpclient is an async operation, and I can't seem to `await` the creation of a task, so I ended up creating an anonymous function and blocking inside of that.

This is probably the wrong approach, but I don't know how else to go about it.

**Method that starts the tasks:**

```
    private static void InitWorkers()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < max_workers; i++)
        {
            Task task = new Task((object state) => { DoWork(state).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }, $"worker_task{i}", TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            ProcessingTasks.TryAdd($"worker_task{i}", task);
            processedStats.TryAdd($"worker_task{i}", new Stat());

            task.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're using async methods, why aren't you using `await` or `Task.ContinueWith()` instead? I have a feeling that `GetResult()` is blocking for you but it's hard to tell for sure from just that screenshot.

Comment: @xxbbcc Probably because I'm new to multithreading in C#. I imagine I'm making a lot of naive mistakes. The tasks are long-running, and are making async calls to `HttpClient`, I'm spooling up multiple tasks to run in parallel. Adding mroe code for context

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: Yes; you should learn more about how `async` works.  Stephen Cleary has lots of good blog posts. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Using `await` with async methods is much simpler than going all manual. If you need to handle async functions manually, you _can_ do so but you should never use `GetResult()` or `.Result` because they block. You need to use `ContinueWith` or `WhenAll` / `WhenAny` to implement continuation logic.

Comment: @xxbbcc Gotcha. I may be describing this poorly. I don't want continuation logic at the moment. I'll be making httprequests for weeks, the tasks are there to provide multiple parallel requests at a time instead of waiting for one request at a time to return. I only am using `async` methods because `HttpClient` runs requests asynchronously. I am not sure if `async` methods are even necessary inside of tasks. I'm going to try and eliminate the usage of async inside of the tasks, and make them all synchronous.

Comment: @SLaks good read, thank you. Going through it now.

Comment: @xxbbcc Removing all async methods and running httpclient synchronously allows me to step through each threads code, and everything still runs in parallel. I am still getting tasks that seemingly stop doing work then start up again after a few moments. But I can at least step through now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which blocks the calling thread while waiting for the task to finish.
Don't do that.

If your method is truly async, you don't need to create a `Task` at all; you can just call it, and it will do its work asynchronously.

If it performs blocking or CPU-bound calls in its synchronous portion, you should use `Task.Run()` to run that in a background thread and wait for the resulting task.

Comment: I'm using tasks since I'm running several processes in parallel, which call web services and end up waiting for responses, these are long running (hours/days). They are async because the `HttpClient ` runs it's request asynchronously. How can I run async methods in parallel with tasks? Am I going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: Those methods are already asynchronous.  You can just `await` them; you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Doesn't that mean I can only run them 1 at a time though? If I want to await 10 HttpRequest at a time, I thought I need to run 10 parallel tasks. If I `await` a `HttpClient` call, it just waits for it to return then goes onto the next one vs running 10 at a time.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: You're looking for `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: I don't want to wait for the tasks to return immediately, but rather them constantly make new HttpRequests over and over until the queue (tens of millions of requests long) is empty. Then I'll wait for them all to run to completion. The issue is during this time some tasks stop doing work, and I want to find out why, and what line they are stuck on. I have a sneaking suspicion that I am starting the parallel tasks wrong.